# Proof validity for a question about union of MST

Tags: graph-theory

A question was put up:
let  $G=(V,E)$ be a connected, undirected graph with weights on its edges. Let $T_1 = (V,E_1)$ and $T_2 = (V,E_2)$ be two different minimal spanning trees of $G$. Prove that in the United Graph $(V, E_1\cup E_2)$ there is a cycle with at least one pair of edges with the same weight

I am trying to understand what may be wrong with the following (simple) proof:

Take an edge $e$ that is in $T_1$ and not in $T_2$. Add it to $T_2$ and now $T_2+e$ has a cycle. Now it is not possible for $e$ to be the heaviest (greater than all other edges) in that cycle because otherwise, it wouldn't have appeared in $T_1$ (Kruskal). It is also not possible for the largest edge in that circle which is not $e$, let's call it $e_{\max}$, to make $w(e_\max) > w(e)$ because then $e_\max$ wouldn't have appeared in $T_2$. Therefore edge $e$ has the same weight as the maximal-weight edge in that cycle.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This solution is correct. Another way to see this (less rigorous) is to notice that to have two distinct MSTs, Kruskal's algorithm has to reach a point where it has a choice to pick any one of two edges of the same weight that are part of a cycle.